# How do I 'fake' a form POST request on the commandline in ssh with python?

Tags: python, ssh, command-line-arguments

I have a small question about a problem I encountered writing my first python web application.

I have a form on my site which action is a python file. The forms posts the values of 2 inputboxes in a post request and my pythonfile will catch those and do something with them. When testing my program I'd like to be able to post these parameters on the command line when in ssh, something like:

python twitter.py -user1="bob" -user2="labla"

However I can't seem to get it to work and couldn't find anything on google.

For now my python file looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgi
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()
import nltk
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

reshtml = """Content-Type: text/html\n"""
print reshtml 

user1 = form['user1'].value
user2 = form['user2'].value


print user1 + "  , " + user2
```

**So how do I 'fake' a form POST request on the commandline in ssh with python?**

Comment: Try [cURL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL)

Comment: ok when I do this I get a 500 error: curl -F "user1=bob" "user2=labla" http://mydomain.com/twitter2.py, any idea whats wrong?

Comment: See: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html for more.  I haven't a lot of experience with it and don't have it on the system available to me now, so can't provide much more than the suggestion.  I'm not even 100% sure you can make it work this way, but I once used the PHP cURL implementation to do this sort of testing, so expect it can be done.  Sorry I can't help more.

Comment: Do you mean run your script passing those parameters on the command line? Or actually POSTing the data from the command line (as though it had come from a form in a browser)?

Comment: If, as the other comments suggest, you actually want to post to the server, try 'curl -v -d "user1=bob" -d "user2=labla" <address>'. If you're getting 500 errors you need to see if your server side code is printing anything.

Comment: Thanks Steve, I tried your line and got a 500 again, however then I tried it on another server of mine and then it worked, so I gues my one server is just not working properly. Any idea why I can run scripts on that server with python script.py but not with curl and post arguments?

Comment: and yes I meant the last thing you mentioned. However how would you go about doing the first scenario you described?

Comment: I know this isn't a python answer, but if you are just trying to do testing of a web app i've used and really liked tamperdata for firefox- https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/ that wont of course help if youre trying to automate something :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [httplib2](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/) to POST requests to a server. For file uploading (multipart requests) you should use [Poster](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/poster/0.6.0).

You might need to GET the form before you can POST it your server checks for security tokens (hidden fields or cookies)